# Combining vertex buffers

Tags: javascript, webgl

I have an issue, the problem is that vertex arrays are stored separately in object file, so they look like that (not a real data):

```
positions: [
  1, 0.5, 0.3,
  3.0, 0.5, 0.3,
  0.3, 0.5, 0.3,
  -0.4, 0.5, 0.2
],
normals: [
  0.5, 0.1, 0.3,
  0.2, 0.5, 0.2,
  0.3, 0.1, 0.3,
  0.6, 0.3, 0.7
],
uv: [
  0.3, 0.2,
  0.1, 0.1,
  0.7, 0.6,
  0.4, 0.3
]
```

The problem is that I can't store it in single vertex buffer so I should have something like this:

```
vertices: [
  1, 0.5, 0.3, 0.5, 0.1, 0.3, 0.3, 0.2,
  3.0, 0.5, 0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.2, 0.1, 0.1,
  0.3, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3, 0.1, 0.3, 0.7, 0.6,
  -0.4, 0.5, 0.2, 0.6, 0.3, 0.7, 0.4, 0.3
]
layout: [["float", 3], ["float", 3], ["float", 2]]
```

e.g. concat each row of each array to make so I can use it in vertex array

Is there are any algorithms or atleast, how that process is called to know where to dig

Comment: The closest term is probably "interleaving", but it's really just copying the right amount of values from each array in turn. If you tell us which language you're using you can probably get a more concrete answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work:

```
function interleaveVertices(spec, sources) {
  const vertices = [];
  while (sources[0].length > 0) {
    for (let i = 0; i < spec.length; i++) {
      Array.prototype.push.apply(vertices, sources[i].splice(0, spec[i]));
    }
  }
  return { vertices: vertices, layout: spec.map(s => ["float", s]) };
}
```

Call as

```
interleaveVertices([3,3,2], [data.positions, data.normals, data.uv]);
```